# Explicit address for camera calibration file

Tags: calibration, roslaunch, camera1394, camera, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a few different platforms that are all using the same package.  Each platform has a different stereo camera calibration file.yaml

Each platform has its own launch file, which gets called (roughly) this way:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="camera1394_nodelet" args="load camera1394/driver left_manager">
<rosparam file="/home/turtlebot/workingDir/cam_info/00b09d0100c8851b.yaml" /> 
<param name="guid" value="00b09d0100c8851b" />
</node>
```

Which seems to work, but within each yaml file the camera_info_url is defined this way:

```
camera_info_url: package://hast/cam_info/left_00b09d0100c8851b.yaml
```

but I would rather call it this way:

```
camera_info_url: /home/turtlebot/BitSync/hast/workingDir/cam_info/left_00b09d0100c8851b.yaml
```

This way I can keep and update the files in a "central server" (via bittorrent sync) instead of embedded within the package on each platform.  However, the second method fails and does not load the yaml file properly.

Is there a different way to define the camera parameters, or am I stuck with the file in each package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194717/explicit-address-for-camera-calibration-file/) by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like many other ROS camera drivers, `camera1394` uses the [camera_info_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager) package for resolving camera configuration information. That package can handle [many URL options](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#details).

If I understand the question correctly, you want to store calibration files for all your cameras together, somewhere separate from your ROS packages. The easiest way to do that is via the `${NAME}` substitution parameter, which gets resolved to the name of each specific device, `00b09d0100c8851b` in your example.

To accomplish that, set the URL this way:

```
camera_info_url: file:///home/turtlebot/BitSync/hast/workingDir/cam_info/${NAME}.yaml
```

Then, store all your calibration files in that directory using each camera's unique 16 hex digit name plus the `.yaml` suffix.

You can even use the identical URL for calibrating the camera initially, `camera_info_manager` will store the file in the specified directory. After that, you would need to update the bit torrent manually.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-10-14**:
Would this also be called during the launch file as:

```
<rosparam file="/home/turtlebot/workingDir/cam_info/${NAME}.yaml" />
```

?

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-10-14**:
Thanks, that did work.  Just FYI for others, no, the launch file needs to have the actual name of the yaml file:

```
<rosparam file="/home/turtlebot/BitSync/hast/workingDir/cam_info/00b09d0100c884f8.yaml" />
```

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-10-15**:
That's right, `${NAME}` is resolved only for the URL parameter, not in the launch file itself.